# index changes in try-catch & threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to download a file in multiple parts simultaneously  for that I am using threads

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread chunkThread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("try_index" + i);
                    });
                    chunkThread.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("catch_index" + i);
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("here");
                }
            }
```

since downloading works fine I cleared that code 
when I watch the Console.Writelines it always writes wrong 
I thought its gonna write

```
try_index0
here
try_index1
try_index2
try_index3
try_index4
```

but the result is

```
here
try_index1
try_index2
try_index4
try_index5
try_index5
```

or something like that but always not I wanted and always a 5 involves
for parts of the download I keep a list with a start and end bytes of the parts and since it gets 5 my code crashes
it is something about new thread but I am too noob to understand 
how can I fix ?

Comment: It's a very common gotcha! Create a copy of the loop variable inside the loop, see the linked answer

Comment: @Jawad I dont care about order.I care about the right indexes

Comment: @canton7 if I dont use new Thread I dont get any wrong index its not about closures

Comment: @eomer It very much is about closures: people hit this problem all the time. Just try it ;)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { int j = i; ... new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("try_index " + j)); ... }`

Comment: @canton7 now I get it thank you!!